Using PowerShell splatting is resulting in 'Unknow argument' error
I am using splatting to create a custom connector as below,
$connectorParameters = @{
        "df" = 'C:\OpenApi.json'
        "pf" = 'C:\apiProperties.json'
        "env" = "d2000000-3b68-4306-bf05-00000000000"
        "if" = 'C:\icon.png'
        "id" = "d2000000-3b68-4306-bf05-1111111111"
    }

pac connector update @connectorParameters

the following error is thrown (same error for each of the argument), passing the parameters directly works as expected.  I am using splatting for the first time, maybe i am doing some basic mistake.

Error: An unknown argument -df:C:\OpenApi.json was passed.

Note: I have tried with single quotes, double quotes all with the same error.

I'm not sure you can use splatting here since the command requires parameters in format -df filename etc.

I thought the splatting would automatically introduce '-' when a splat variable is expanded.

It does, that's not the problem. PowerShell adds the : between parameter name and the argument value which is probably what trips up pac

Got it, the 'pac connector' commands are not PowerShell commands, this is the reason why the splatting does not work.  Thanks.


PowerShell supports two forms of splatting:

array-based splatting, primarily for use with external programs.

hashtable-based splatting, primarily for use with PowerShell-native commands.


While you can technically use the hashtable form with external programs too, the resulting process command line is unlikely to be supported, because PowerShell translates the hashtable entries into -<key>:<value> arguments, a syntax that few external programs support.[1]
Therefore, use array-based splatting with external programs (CLIs), where the option names and values must form individual elements of the array:
# Construct an *array* (@(...)) and specify each option name
# and argument *individually* as an element.
$connectorParameters = @(
        '-df', 'C:\OpenApi.json',
        '-pf', 'C:\apiProperties.json',
        '-env', 'd2000000-3b68-4306-bf05-00000000000',
        '-if', 'C:\icon.png',
        '-id', 'd2000000-3b68-4306-bf05-1111111111'
    )

# This is the equivalent of:
#   pac connector update -df C:\OpenApi.json -pf C:\apiProperties.json -env d2000000-3b68-4306-bf05-00000000000 -if C:\icon.png -id d2000000-3b68-4306-bf05-1111111111
pac connector update @connectorParameters

Note:

The above @(...) array subexpression operation creates a regular, single-dimensional array (of type [object[]]); placing pairs of option names and their arguments each on a separate line is purely a formatting choice, for readability.

Unlike with hashtable-based splatting, the - before option names must be included in the relevant array elements.

If any array elements contain spaces, PowerShell automatically encloses them in "..." behind the scenes when it constructs the process command line (on Windows).

Strictly speaking, you don't need splatting with external programs and can pass a variable containing an array as-is; however, you may still choose to use splatting, i.e. referencing the variable with @ rather than $, for conceptual clarity.



[1] (GitHub issue #9343 suggests that the format be changed to separating with a space instead (using separate arguments; -<key> <value>).
